# How to make an reinforcement learning agent learn an endless runner?

Tags: unity-game-engine, machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I'm tried to train a reinforcement learning agent to play an endless runner game using Unity-ML.

The game is simple: an obstacle is approaching from the side and the agent has to jump at the right timing to overcome it.

As the observation, I have the distance to the next obstacle. Possible actions are 0 - idle; 1 - jump. Rewards are given for longer playtime.

Unfortunately, the agent fails to learn to overcome even the 1st obstacle reliable. I guess this is due too high imbalance on the two actions as the ideal policy would be doing nothing (0) most of the time and jump (1) only at very specific points in time. Additionally, all actions during a jump are meaningless since the agent cannot jump while in the air.

How can I improve the learning such that it convergence nevertheless? Any suggestions what to look into?

Current trainer config:

```
EndlessRunnerBrain:
  gamma: 0.99
  beta: 1e-3
  epsilon: 0.2
  learning_rate: 1e-5
  buffer_size: 40960
  batch_size: 32
  time_horizon: 2048
  max_steps: 5.0e6
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's difficult to say without seeing the exact code that's being used for the reinforcement learning algorithm. Here are some steps worth exploring:

- How long are you letting the agent train? Depending on the complexity of the game environment, it very well may take thousands of episodes for the agent to learn to avoid its first obstacle.
- Experiment with the `Frameskip` property of the `Academy` object. This permits the agent to only take an action after a number of frames have passed. Increasing this value may increase the speed of learning in more simple games.
- Adjust the learning rate. The learning rate determines how heavily the agent weights new information versus old information. You're using a very small learning rate; try increasing it by a couple decimal places.
- Adjust epsilon. Epsilon determines how often a random action is taken. Given a state and an epsilon rate of 0.2, your agent will take a random action 20% of the time. The other 80% of the time, it will choose the *(state, action)* pair with the highest associated reward. You can try reducing or increasing this value to see if you get better results. Since you know you'll want more random actions in the beginning of training, you can even "decay" epsilon with each episode. If you start with an epsilon value of 0.5, after each game episode is completed, reduce epsilon by a small value, say 0.00001 or so.
- Change the way the agent is rewarded. Instead of rewarding the agent for each frame it stays alive, perhaps you could reward the agent for each obstacle it successfully jumps over.
- Are you sure that the given `time_horizon` and `max_steps` provide enough runway for the game to complete an episode?

Hope this helps, and best of luck!